# How to add custom java objects to Velocity context in Maven archetype plugin for dynamic file generation

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-plugin, velocity, maven-archetype

First of all apologies to create a duplicate question. I searched a lot and was not able to find the answer apart from the below question which was asked a year ago. I don't have enough reputation to comment and ask on that  thread itself.

[Can I add custom objects to Velocity context with Maven archetype plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360904/can-i-add-custom-objects-to-velocity-context-with-maven-archetype-plugin)

I am wondering if a solution exists to the problem or some workaround. I am able to use substitute variables and use if-else constructs for dynamic file generation but I am not sure how to pass a java object and generate the class based on the contents of the passed object. 
Say I have a list "list" object of fields provided by user at run time I want to populate a class whose fields are in that "list" object. How to achieve this?